# Neo4j: How to fix one of the node in match clause?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

For clauses like `MATCH  (a:Address)-[:BelongTo]->(w1:Wallet), (a)-[r0:BelongTo]->(w2:Wallet) WHERE ID(w1)>ID(w2) WITH w1, w2...`, is it possible to make sure that ex. w1 is always a fixed node? If yes, is it possible to decide on the node by choosing the node having ex. the minimum value for a certain property over all the nodes which could also be w1?

More concretely, for example, an address a belong to wallet a, b, c with a>b>c in terms of ID. Then normally these rows of result will be returned:

```
w1 w2
--------
a    b
b    c
a    c
```

I only want these two rows of result to be returned:

```
w1 w2
--------
a    b
a    c
```

Note: I want the query try to get every pair of wallets to both an address belongs to. All addresses which belongs to two or more wallet should be included in return if a is returned.

So for example, If there are two addresses which belong to three different wallets, what would the query you posted do? 
More concretely, if addresses a1 and a2 belong to b1, c1, d1 and b2, c2, d2 respectively, (with b1 > c1 > d1> b2> c2>d2 in terms of id)

I want it to return:

```
a    w1   w2
-----------
a1  b1    c1
a1  b1    d1
a2  b2    c2
a2  b2    d2
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Not clear what your current query is trying to do and why. Is it trying to get every pair of wallets for a single address, or across all addresses?

Comment: Across all addresses. I want it try to get every pair of wallets to both an address belongs to. All addresses which belongs to two or more wallet should be included in return if a is returned. I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this by finding (for each a:Address), the :Wallet with the minimum id. After you match to this :Wallet, you can match to all the other :Wallets.

```
MATCH  (a:Address)-[:BelongTo]->(w1:Wallet)
WITH a, min(id(w1)) as minId
// since we have the minId, we can do a fast lookup of the node
MATCH (minW:Wallet)
WHERE id(minW) = minId
// now get all the others
MATCH (a)-[:BelongTo]->(w2:Wallet)
WHERE minW <> w2
...
```

If you don't care how the fixed node is taken, and if it only matters for the duration of the query, it may be easier to collect all the :Wallet nodes, take the first node in the collection, and then UNWIND the rest into rows and continue the query:

```
MATCH  (a:Address)-[:BelongTo]->(w:Wallet)
WITH a, collect(w) as wallets
WITH a, head(wallets) as w1, wallets
UNWIND tail(wallets) as w2
...
```